# how to get full word from short sms word like wrk for Work?

Tags: java, str-replace

I do like to replace short word to its original word like

```
1.>wrd---word

2.>congrats---congratulations 

3.>oswm-----------owesome

4.>awsum ------- owesome
```

emoticons does not contain all this type of word

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post some code and ask questions about where you are getting stuck.

Comment: You gotta prepare your own database based for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you actually *know* what you want to replace with what, you probably want to set up some sort of `Map<String, String>` and then loop through each word `w` in the input string and replace it with `yourMap.get(w)`.

Here's an example snippet for you:

```
Map<String, String> dict = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("wrd", "word");
    put("congrats", "congratulations");
    put("oswm", "awesome");
    put("awsum", "awesome");
}};


String input = "Here's an awsum example wrd, congrats!";

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

while (m.find()) {
    String toInsert = m.group();
    if (dict.containsKey(toInsert))
        toInsert = dict.get(toInsert);
    m.appendReplacement(result, toInsert);

}

m.appendTail(result);

System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
Here's an awesome example word, congratulations!
```

Comment: She wants to resolve original word from shortform, your answer tells how to store it, I guess she need a strong DB to perform this

Comment: @JigarJoshi: she didn't say anything about DB

Comment: @SoniaGupta, *What* does not have any API?

Comment: Not that I know of, no. Why would there? I just presented you all the code that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Build you're self a dictionary.  Load that into something like a HashMap and start running.

I'm sure something like the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) might be useful or simply use something like [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good resource I found: http://www.internetslang.com/

Unfortunately they do not let you to download the full list of acronyms you can do it manually  during several minutes. Just 26 clicks, then select all+copy+paste.

Comment: its for emotions,i already done that but not for uncompleted word like i mention